# Jetty Connector not throwing exception when connection is closed

Tags: http, embedded-jetty

I am new to Jetty and I am working on a problem as follows

1. A remote sender sends a HTTP 1.1 request to a servlet hosted on a embedded Jetty
2. The sender also has a timeout of 30s for the connection
3. At the receiver end, processing takes more than 60s and hence the SENDER closes the connection in the mean time
4. When the sender is trying to send the reply data as a synchronous reply over the same connection there is no exception getting thrown to handle

I see that this can be accomplished only using traditional IO and not NIO connectors but Jetty 9.1.4 uses only  NIO connectors.

Also The problem does not happen when the data being written is large which is because of how NIO works I guess

What are some options to overcome this issue?

EDIT 1:

Receiver side info :

> HTTP server settings; name=Global http server, host:port=0.0.0.0:4080,
>   minThreads=1,  maxThreads=500, maxLingerTimeMs=-1,
>   restartableMinBytes=102400, tempFileMinutesToLive=240

Connector:

> Idle Timeout : 30 seconds Linger time : -1

Ran netstat on the receiver(the one taking more than 60s) on 4080 port and found that the TCP connection status changed from ESTABLISHED to CLOSE_WAIT(after 30s) and then finally disappeared.

Comment: More details of your setup / configuration are needed.  Also, you do know that HTTP supports half-closed connections, right?  A Sender (aka web client) can (and often do) close only half the connection, allowing a response to still be received and read.  The question as it stands doesn't have enough information to render an answer.

Comment: Thanks @Joakim. I was not aware of half-closed connections. I just did a read now. I have updated with info I could gather. Please let me know if you need more information.